# Redirect customers who purchased a specific product away from the single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to redirect customers, who bought the product with the ID "12514".

My question is:

> Where can I set the product ID, so that only on that single page starts a redirection (now it is on every single product page), if the user already bought that product once?

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'single_product_redirect_logged_in_purchased' );

function single_product_redirect_logged_in_purchased() { 
    if ( ! is_product() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;  
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $product_id = get_queried_object_id();
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect('/custom-url');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing for the user, they try and look at something they have bought and each time they try and view it they are sent somewhere else?

Comment: Nope, it's an online course... and when the user bought it, it should redirect him directly into the course.

Comment: So a simple *go to course* button wouldn't be good enough?  I find web sites that jump around because they know better than you do annoying at times (IMHO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a extra condition in the if statement

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'single_product_redirect_logged_in_purchased' );

function single_product_redirect_logged_in_purchased() { 
    if ( ! is_product() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;  
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $product_id = get_queried_object_id();
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id ) && $product_id == 12514 ) {
        wp_safe_redirect('/custom-url');
        exit;
    }
}
```